# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

Сегодня запустил на своем пк один проект, который был создан 7.1 версии php. У меня стоит 7.4  и выдаёт напоминалку на экране:

**Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null**
Ссылкой на эту строку в коде:

**if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php'))**

Как изменить код, да бы убрать эту ошибку
Вот код целиком из файла:

```
   <?php

      class Core {
        protected $currentController = 'Pages';
        protected $currentMethod = 'index';
        protected $params = [];

        public function __construct(){

          $url = $this->getUrl();


if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[0]). '.php')){
            $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
            unset($url[0]);

          }

          require_once '../app/controllers/'. $this->currentController . '.php';

          $this->currentController = new $this->currentController;

          if(isset($url[1])){
            if(method_exists($this->currentController, $url[1])){
              $this->currentMethod = $url[1];
              unset($url[1]);
            }
          }

          $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];

          call_user_func_array([$this->currentController, $this->currentMethod], $this->params);
        }

        public function getUrl(){
          if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
            $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            $url = explode('/', $url);
            return $url;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: В коде надо проверить, что если `GET['url']` не существует, то сделать что-то.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! У меня так зароботал код: if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        if(file_exists('../app/controllers/' . ucwords($url[1]). '.php')){
          $this->currentController = ucwords($url[0]);
          unset($url[0]);
        
        }
      }

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о том, что переменная `$url` у вас `null`. Значит нужно проверить этот момент. Например создать метод с проверкой и опираться на него:

```
public function stringIsEmptyOrNull($string) {
    // да, тут можно использовать метод "empty()", но как мне кажется это не совсем то
    return $string === '' || $string === null;        
}
```

и дальше использовать:

```
public function __construct(){ 
    // ...
    $url = $this->getUrl();

    if ($this->stringIsEmptyOrNull($url))
        throw new Exception('url пустой, дядя!');
    // ... 
}
```